# how to access jupyter-kernel-gateway Rest api from internet?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-kernel

I created REST api using [jupyter kernel gateway](https://jupyter-kernel-gateway.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http-mode.html) by following [tutorial](https://ndres.me/post/jupyter-notebook-rest-api/)

```
jupyter kernelgateway \
    --KernelGatewayApp.api='kernel_gateway.notebook_http' \
    --KernelGatewayApp.seed_uri='jyhost-FR/rest_api.ipynb'
```

I can access this from my laptop using http://localhost:8888/convert?angle=180

Now I want to use it in my prototype app, that is access it from the internet, to create a small demo(just 1 user).

What is the simplest way to do it?

I tried changing value `~/.jupyter/jupyter_kernel_gateway_config.py`

```
c.KernelGatewayApp.ip = '*'
```

But how to access it via internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using ngrok for port forwarding

`ngrok http 9460`  // where 9460 is your port from

```
http://localhost:9460/
```